# How do I use Magento Core Modules French Language Pack for a view

Tags: magento-1.7, language

I have installed Magento Core Modules French Language Pack in my Magento setup.

But I am not sure how it works. I haven't seen any documentation.

My Magento setup is divided in different views for the different languages.

How can I apply this module for a view so that part of the website is french?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the locale in your store settings:

- In the admin, navigate to `System > Config > General`
- Change the store dropdown to the desired store to change the language
- Select the appropriate language from the locale dropdown
- Click 'save'

[image]

Comment: For some reason the page is still in english. The menu is still in english. (My Account, My WishlistMy Cart, Checkout, Log In) Why is that? I did the changes you propose.

Comment: Your theme may not be set up for translation. Disable your custom package/theme and try it on the base/default package and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I haven't tried what you proposed yet. But how do I apply it to my custom them?

Comment: Your theme should be using the translator for all echo statements including static navigational elements. For instance instead of `<ul><li>Home</li></ul>` use this: `<ul><li><?php echo $this->__('Home'); ?></li></ul>`

Comment: I copied the main them to then modify it. Anyways I will look into it.

Comment: I cannot find where the menu is hidden... But I did manage to find this in the hello.phtml file : "<p class="hello"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Hello, [...]". So I assume it's like this all over.

Comment: I solved it. The problem is that I used Francais (Canada) and not Francais (France).

Comment: Ah, yes. Nicely done.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11160/discussion-between-jean-nicolas-boulay-desjardins-and-philwinkle)